# Passing command arguments Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to pass command arguments with a batch file. How would I do that? I have a little program set up but I don't know how to get the command arguments.. or really how to make a command.

```
@echo OFF
title Name pl0x
color 0a
:start
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT= %=%
IF "%INPUT%"=="/mynameis" (
goto :init
) ELSE (
goto :start
)
:init
Pause&Exit
REM Here, I'd print the name, like this: echo.Hello, %name%
REM I just don't have the variable. And I don't know how to set it.
```

Comment: If I resolved this or your last question remember to use the ACCEPT button to accept my answers, thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An argument is a delimited word by a space wich you can use like a parameter in a application.

Then if call a script like this:

```
Script.Bat word1 word2 word3_word4-word5
```

The arguments are:

```
Argument 1 = "word1"
Argument 2 = "word2"
Argument 3 = "word3_word4-word5" (Because any space).
```

In Batch arguments are stored in special vars from **%1** to **%255** where **%1** equals to the "Argument 1".

%0 equals to the current script name or procedure name.

%* joins all th arguments

..And the special modifier **~** expand the argument without double quotes.

Then if we have this code:

```
@Echo OFF
If /I "%~1" EQU "/Print" (Echo: You called the function "%~1" with the value: "%~2"))
```

We are checking if argument 1 is equals to "/Print", then if is equals prints the value for the switch, the second argument.

Then you can call your bat like this:

```
Script.bat /Print Hello!
```

Learn more about Batch arguments here: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html

Comment: **%0 to %9** is the range - they do not go up to %255.  You have to use SHIFT to access any parameters past the 9th one.

Comment: That's the range to print/use them, but what I said is they are stored up to number %255 (%10-%255 are imaginary, hiddenly, but usable with shift like you said), you can't store/use/shift more than 255 args.

Answer (score 2):

Arguments are done with %1 %2, etc

So if you have mynameis.bat  %1 will contain test

Comment: any idea how I can use this in a command? Like I'd want the user to do /mynameis Name

Comment: Are you talking about named arguments? Or is mynameis a program or batch file?

Comment: Named arguments... I think, yes. Because mynameis is not a program/batch file